# How should I secure T&P relief valve discharge copper pipe to the wall?

Tags: tankless

The copper pipe is the T&P relief valve discharge pipe and the white pex is for condensate.

What's the correct way to secure this pipe to the wall?

[image: Photo of copper T&P discharge pipe]

Comment: there is no one correct way ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pipe+strap&iax=images&ia=images ............ https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cable+tie+anchor&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Be sure there is no shut off in the T&P relief valve and that the tubing does not reduce in size. It should be open on the outlet, not plumbed into a drain.